# Don't know what format date is to be able to parse it '[1252457867]'

Tags: datetime

I have a date/time field from a shopping cart API feed, but I don't know what format it is in and I don't have access to the database.

What could [1252457867] be for a date?
These dates are all within the last couple weeks

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like seconds elapsed since Jan. 1st, 1970 12:00AM.

Use this function to get the date:

```
var baseDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
var transactionDate = baseDate.AddSeconds(1252457867);
```

This will output {9/9/2009 12:57:47 AM} PST

**EDIT: **
If you need UTC:

```
var utcDate = baseDate.AddSeconds(1252457867).ToUniversalTime();
```

This outputs {9/9/2009 7:57:47 AM}

--Adam

Comment: Daniel Brückner: The reason of the three hours difference is of course that Unix timestamps are in UTC but the .NET Framework converted the date to adaminst's local timezone.

Answer (score 13):

Clearly a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

1252457867 = 09 Sep 2009 - 02:57:47

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like seconds since the [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (January 1, 1970).